# Unirest - Setting proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, unirest

How do I set a proxy once for the rest of the requests with [unirest](http://unirest.io/nodejs.html)? I get `Request.proxy is not a function`

```
var Request = require('unirest');
Request.proxy('217.23.3.15:11100');
unirest.get('https://api.ipify.org/t')
.end(function (response) {
 console.log(response.body);
 });
```

Comment: Anyone can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this will work fine :

```
    unirest.get('https://api.ipify.org/t')
    .proxy('http://217.23.3.15:11100')
    .end(function (response) {
      console.log(response.body);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Unirest support http proxy for now. The code should be as follows:

```
var Request = require('unirest');
Request.proxy('http://217.23.3.15:11100');
unirest.get('https://api.ipify.org/t')
.end(function (response) {
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

Every request will be passed through proxy once you declare

```
Request.proxy('http://217.23.3.15:11100');
```

Comment: "Request.proxy is not a function"