# Find string and delete line - Node.JS

Tags: node.js, string, file, search, fs

How to read file, search for string and delete line in node.js? I have tried

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('shuffle.txt', function read(err, data) {
if (err) {
throw err;
}

lastIndex = function(){
for (var i = data_array.length - 1; i > -1; i--)
if (data_array[i].match('user1'))
return i;
}()

delete data_array[lastIndex];

});
```

Comment: A number of problems.  Where is 'data_array' getting initialized?  Also, the data from your file is only available in the callback function.  lastIndex is a function, not a value, so delete data_array[lastIndex] is probably not what you are looking for.  Break the problem down and test it a piece at a time.

Comment: After deleting the line, do you have to update the content of the file?

Comment: Yes, thanks alot for your answer. Is there any solution in javascript for this as well?

Comment: I wrote the answer in javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your help! If its not too much could you help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52935965/unirest-setting-proxy/52937907#52937907 (Btw I just meant client side javascript as this is client side node.js?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say we have a text file, **shuffle.txt** contains the following content

```
john
doe
user1 
some keyword
last word
```

Now we read the **shuffle.txt** file and then search for '**user1**' keyword. If any line contains the '**user1**', then we will remove the line.

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('shuffle.txt', {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw error;

    let dataArray = data.split('\n'); // convert file data in an array
    const searchKeyword = 'user1'; // we are looking for a line, contains, key word 'user1' in the file
    let lastIndex = -1; // let say, we have not found the keyword

    for (let index=0; index<dataArray.length; index++) {
        if (dataArray[index].includes(searchKeyword)) { // check if a line contains the 'user1' keyword
            lastIndex = index; // found a line includes a 'user1' keyword
            break; 
        }
    }

    dataArray.splice(lastIndex, 1); // remove the keyword 'user1' from the data Array

    // UPDATE FILE WITH NEW DATA
    // IN CASE YOU WANT TO UPDATE THE CONTENT IN YOUR FILE
    // THIS WILL REMOVE THE LINE CONTAINS 'user1' IN YOUR shuffle.txt FILE
    const updatedData = dataArray.join('\n');
    fs.writeFile('shuffle.txt', updatedData, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log ('Successfully updated the file data');
    });

});
```

Here, if a line contains '**user1**' keyword, we are removing the entire line. The new **shuffle.txt** file will be no longer contains a line with 'user1' keyword. The updated **shuffle.txt** file looks like

```
john
doe
some keyword
last word
```

For more information check the [doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html).

Comment: Great answer! What would be the logic to use to update a large text file when using fs.writeStream? See my problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71191431/how-to-delete-lines-of-text-from-file-with-createwritestream-with-node-js