# Question about Find string and delete line - Node.JS

Tags: node.js, readlines

[Find string and delete line - Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52938329/find-string-and-delete-line-node-js/63295645#63295645)

```
var fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('shuffle.txt', {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw error;

  let dataArray = data.split('\n'); // convert file data in an array
  const searchKeyword = 'user1'; // we are looking for a line, contains,       key word 'user1' in the file
  let lastIndex = -1; // let say, we have not found the keyword

  for (let index=0; index<dataArray.length; index++) {
    if (dataArray[index].includes(searchKeyword)) { // check if a line    contains the 'user1' keyword
      lastIndex = index; // found a line includes a 'user1' keyword
      break; 
    }
  }

  dataArray.splice(lastIndex, 1); // remove the keyword 'user1' from the data Array

  // UPDATE FILE WITH NEW DATA
  // IN CASE YOU WANT TO UPDATE THE CONTENT IN YOUR FILE
  // THIS WILL REMOVE THE LINE CONTAINS 'user1' IN YOUR shuffle.txt FILE
  const updatedData = dataArray.join('\n');
  fs.writeFile('shuffle.txt', updatedData, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log ('Successfully updated the file data');
  });

});
```

This link explains how to find a string and delete lines but only delete one user1 at the time. I have many lines with user1, how can I delete all:

```
john
doe
some keyword
user1
last word
user1
user1
```

Also the opposite. How can I delete all the lines and leave only the user1 lines?

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of the [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

Basically, you call `filter()` on an array, and define a callback function that checks every item of that array.

If the checking function returns `true` for a particular item, keep that item - put it in a new array
If the checking function returns `false`, do not put the item in the new array

So, in your case, once you have read all the lines into an array (up to line 6 in your code), use the filter function:

```
// Delete all instances of user1
let newDataArray = dataArray.filter(line => line !== "user1")
```

```
// Delete everything except user1
let newDataArray = dataArray.filter(line => line === "user1")
```

```
// Delete any lines that have the text 'user1' somewhere inside them
let newDataArray = dataArray.filter(line => !line.includes("user1"))
```

Then, just like you have done in your code, use the `join()` function on `newDataArray()` and write the file.

---

To rewrite your code,

```
var fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('shuffle.txt', {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw error;

  let dataArray = data.split('\n'); // convert file data in an array
  const searchKeyword = 'user1'; // we are looking for a line, contains,       key word 'user1' in the file

  // Delete all instances of user1
  let newDataArray = dataArray.filter(line => line !== searchKeyword)

  // UPDATE FILE WITH NEW DATA
  const updatedData = newDataArray.join('\n');

  fs.writeFile('shuffle.txt', updatedData, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log ('Successfully updated the file data');
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks I tried to modify the script but I got lost completely. Where exactly add 
    
"let newDataArray = dataArray.filter(line => line !== "user1")"

and what to take out from the original script?

Comment: I rewrote the code you had given, hope it is clear now

Comment: 1) It works with : // Delete all instances of user1
  let newDataArray = dataArray.filter(line => line !== searchKeyword)

Comment: 2) It works with : // Delete everything except user1
// let newDataArray = dataArray.filter(line => line === searchKeyword)

Comment: 3) it doesn't work with :// Delete any lines that have the text 'user1' somewhere inside them
let newDataArray = dataArray.filter(line => line.includes (searchKeyword))

the result is like number 2) Delete everything except user1

Comment: Thanks William for your help

Comment: Oops! Yep 3) should be negated, I will fix it. No problem